# Obtener access_token de un API con OAuth 2.0 desde Android

Tags: android, curl, oauth2

Buenos dias. Vengo con una duda, resulta que mi aplicacion tiene que comunicarse con un WS para obtener el access_token y asi poder utilizar los metodos de este. El WS utiliza OAuth 2.0 y el administrador me paso las consultas al WS en cURL. Eh tratado de hacerlo desde PostMan pero me larga error y desde consola de Windows si me funciona bien.
El cURL para obtener el access_token es el siguiente:

```
curl -X POST -vu <client_id>:<client_secret> http://<ip ws>:8080/oauth/token -H "Accept: application/json" -d "password=<password>&username=<user>&grant_type=password&scope=read%20write&client_secret=<client_secret>&client_id=<client_id>"
```

Este codigo desde consola de Windows funcion perfecto, me retorna el access_token.
Mira pregunta es como realizo esta consulta desde mi aplicacion de Android?
Intente con HttpURLConnect pero no me ah funcionado.
Necesito ayuda! Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Se sugiere usar **[HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)**, las clases de Apache son obsoletas.

Este es un ejemplo:

```
URL url = new URL("http://<ip ws>:8080/oauth/token");
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(10000); //10 segundos timeout
conn.setConnectTimeout(10000); //10 segundos timeout
conn.setRequestMethod("POST"); //Define método POST.
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", <password>));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", <username>));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", <grant_type>));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("scope", <scope>));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", <client_secret>));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", <client_id>));

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter bwriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
bwriter.write(getQuery(params));
bwriter.flush();
bwriter.close();
os.close();
conn.connect();
```

Comment: Bien y como obtengo el access_token que devuelve?

Comment: Tengo un problema aqui:
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
No me reconoce "NameValuePair"
Tampoco "BasicNameValuePair" y getQuery(params).
Sabes porque puede ser?